# Gaussian hypergeometric function 2F1

Tags: matlab, gaussian

I would like to know if there is any available Gaussian hypergeometric function (2F1 function) code for Matlab.

I perfectly know that in the newest Matlab releases there is the hypergeom function, but it works really slow.

Therefore I was wondering about the existance of any mex function or whatever similar code performing what hypergeom does.

I thank you all in advance for support.

Best regards,
Francesco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [GNU Scientific Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Hypergeometric-Functions.html) implements hypergeometric functions including 2F1.  You shouldn't have too much trouble wrapping that inside a mex-file.

I expect you'll find other sources knocking around on the Internet too.

Do report back and let us know if it does work faster than the intrinsic function.

Answer (score 1):

After googleing a bit in the Internet, I came up with this tool provided within the Mathworks File Exchange:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35008-generation-of-random-variates/content/pfq.m

It consists of 1900 distributions, and among them the Gaussian hypergeometric function 2F1.

Furthermore, it has better performances than the standard hypergeom function.